# What is the solution of this equation on regular languages?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, regular-language

I need to characterize this language:

$$
L = \{ s \in \Sigma^* \, | \, \{s\} \cdot A_1 \subseteq B_1 \land \ldots \land \{s\} \cdot A_n \subseteq B_n \}
$$
where $A_i, B_i$ are all regular languages. My question is whether $L$ is regular or not, and in the positive case how we can construct a regular expression (or an automaton) for it in terms of those for the $A_i, B_i$. I don't even know where to start. Can anyone give me a suggestion, or point me to any literature that may help me in the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L$ is regular.  I'll prove this for $n=1$; then it follows for arbitrary $n$, as the intersection of regular languages is itself regular.

Define

$$L = \{x \in \Sigma^* \mid \{x\} \cdot A \subseteq B\}.$$

I will construct a finite-state automaton $M_L$ for $L$, proving that $L$ is regular.

Let $M_A,M_B$ be deterministic finite-state automata for the languages $A,B$.  WLOG we can assume they have no useless or unreachable states.  Let $s_0,t_0$ denote the start states for $M_A,M_B$.

$M_L$'s states have the form  $\langle s,t \rangle$ or $\langle \bot,t \rangle$, where $s,t$ range over states of $M_A,M_B$, respectively.

$M_L$ has a transition $\langle s,t \rangle \stackrel{c}{\to} \langle s',t' \rangle$ if $M_A$ has a transition $s \stackrel{c}{\to} s'$ and $M_B$ has a transition  $t \stackrel{c}{\to} t'$.  Also, $M_L$ has a transition $\langle \bot,t \rangle \stackrel{\epsilon}{\to} \langle s_0,t \rangle$ for each $t$.

Mark the state $\langle s_0,t \rangle $ as accepting in $M_L$ iff for every path $\langle s_0,t \rangle \leadsto \langle s',t' \rangle$ in $M_L$ such that $s'$ is accepting in $M_A$, $t'$ is accepting in $M_B$. (*)

You should be able to prove that $M_L$ forms a finite-state automaton for $L$.  I'll let you work out the details of the proof.  If you want, you can easily adjust $M_L$ to be deterministic by removing the few $\epsilon$ transitions.  This gives you the result you desired, as well as a constructive algorithm to form an automaton recognizing the language.  Combine this with the standard method (product automaton) for the intersection of multiple regular languages, and you obtain a solution for arbitrary $n$ as well.

---

Footnote (*): Also, you can efficiently find all such states using a single depth-first search.  Let

$$I = \{\langle s',t' \rangle \mid s' \text{ is accepting}, t' \text{ is not accepting}\}.$$

Now do a depth-first search backwards through $M_L$, starting from the set of states $I$ defined as follows, to find all states $R$ that are reachable (going backwards) from $I$.  Mark every state of the form $\langle s_0,t\rangle$ that is not in $R$ as accepting in $M_L$; all other states of $M_L$ are not accepting.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you let me know your name I will acknowledge you in the paper.

Comment: @PietroBraione, you're welcome.  No need, but I appreciate the offer.  Please do check the details here carefully in case I have made a mistake (I make many mistakes).